# Completely remove objects from runtime

Tags: php, memory-management

I'm running a job where I import stock information from loads of suppliers. Some of them have many products, so when I store them in memory it quickly gets pretty heavy.

For that reason, I'd like to - after doing whatever-i-do-with-them - completely unset each supplier.

Each "supplier" is a Reader and a Processor which gets injected into a Manager which will return all data to N writers. The manager stores the Reader and Processor (which is the classes where the big amount of data will be) in a simple array.

Here's a quick demonstration:

```
$first = new stdClass();
$first->name = "I'm an object";
$first->age = 12;

$second = new stdClass();
$first->name = "I'm also an object!";
$first->age = 9;

$arr = array($first, $second);

while ($data = array_shift($arr)) {
    echo "Emptying array one by one... \n";
    //doesn't matter if you unset($data) or do $data=null;
}

//I want this to be empty, but's not
var_dump($first);
```

For now, I do a foreach() on the array and makes the value be passed by reference, which I then passes (by reference) to a cleanup() method. This feels clumsy.

Am I missing something obvious? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you just `$arr = false` to unset the full array when finished?

Comment: The problem is you are moving the values of `$arr` to `$data`.So `$arr` will only be emptied.